# VIM search for characters starting with ampersand

Tags: vim

I have to search for something like `&variable` (and replace with `&variable.test`). I could just do `\&variable`, but vim also shows me all characters starting with `&variable` (`&variableXXX` for instance), which I do not want. I thought this - `/\<\&variable\>` would work, please let me know where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first problem is that `\&` is not a literal `&` its a special regex match that matches branches in vim. To match a literal `&` just use `&`.

The second problem is that `\<` matches the beginning of a keyword by looking to see if the next character is a keyword. However `&` is not normally a keyword so it always fails.

To get around this you can make `&` a keyword by doing

```
set iskeyword+=&
```

Then you can use the regex `\<&variable\>` to match the things you want.

Relevant help pages [`:h iskeyword`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27iskeyword%27), [`:h /\<`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#pattern-atoms) and [`:h \&`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#search-pattern)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: use `/&variable\>`.

You don't want the `\` in front of the `&`. See `help \&`.

Your `\<` is in the wrong place -- it belongs after the `&`, not before, since `&` is not a keyword character (`:help keyword`).

In fact, you don't need the `\<` at all. You could search for `&variable\>` and you would find `&variable` but not `&variableXXX`. You don't have to use `\<` just because you're using `\>`.